# Qt Debugging using Visual Studio Kits

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem with the CDB debugger.

In particular if I try to use the predefined kit MinGW, all the debugging functionalities work correctly, whereas if I try to use the Visual Studio Kit, Qt Creator generates some issue.

Note that I'm using the Visual Studio Express 2012 version and I have installed separately the CDB debugger, following a guide found on the Qt website.

The problem arises only while I'm debugging an application in which there is at least one call to the QFileDialog operations, because for simple application in which I'm not going to use this functionality the debugger works fine.

As soon as the QFileDialog operation is called, in the "Issues" box of the Qt Creator the following errors appear:

- Exception at 0x77444598, code: 0x6ba: RPC server unavailable,
  flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance)
- Exception at 0x77444598, code: 0x8001010e: , flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance)

The strange thing is that my program (the one that I'm debugging) continues to work but if I have put some breakpoints inside my code, these breakpoints will be ignored.

Comment: It seem that QFileDialog redirect exceptions and error from Windows Explorer. I experienced issues with SNACNP.dll of symatec and even GROOVEEX.dll from MS. Removing those components resolve the exception. The exception seem harmless, but annoying while debugging.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/111745/error-when-using-qfiledialog-getopenfilenames